# "Type" error when deserializing kafka avro

Tags: python, serialization, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have this python consumer receiving messages from a topic, the messages are coming to the consumer, but when I try to deserialize the Avro message I am getting this error:

```
self._reader_schema = parse_schema(loads(schema_str)) if schema_str else None
  File "fastavro/_schema.pyx", line 121, in fastavro._schema.parse_schema
  File "fastavro/_schema.pyx", line 207, in fastavro._schema._parse_schema
KeyError: 'type'
```

This is my consumer:

```
import cv2
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry import SchemaRegistryClient
from confluent_kafka.schema_registry.avro import AvroDeserializer

def process_record_confluent(record: bytes, src: SchemaRegistryClient, schema: str):
    deserializer = AvroDeserializer(schema_str=schema, schema_registry_client=src)
    return deserializer(record, None)

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'kafkamessages.dev.orders',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    group_id='payment_orders',
    auto_offset_reset='latest',
    value_deserializer=lambda m: process_record_confluent(m, src=SchemaRegistryClient({'url': 'https://kafka-schema.mysales.dep/'}), schema='{"id": "4"}'),
    consumer_timeout_ms=6000
)

try:
    message_received = False
    for message in consumer:
        message_received = True
        key = message.key.decode('utf-8')
        value = message.value['image']
        print(f'Received message: key={key}, value={value}')
    if not message_received:
        print('No new messages were found.')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    consumer.close()
```

That's my schema:

```
"type": "record",
"name": "Envelope",
"namespace": "xxxxxx",
"fields": [ .....
```

Latest version
1

ID 4
Type AVRO
Subject xxxxxxx
Compatibility BACKWARD

I am expecting to deserialize the message I am getting from kafka topic.

Comment: I think I saw this error mentioned in the confluent kafka github issue before... And the problem is with fastavro, which I think you can uninstall, and use the fallback avro python library

Comment: Otherwise, I don't think `schema=` parameter is necessary... All records already have an ID embedded within them

Comment: Are you able to post your schema?

Comment: @Scott I updated adding the schema

Comment: Thanks for adding the schema -- I can't see the format of your fields, do they follow the format outlined here? https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/#complex-types